# How to browse root directory in linux mint?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, linux-mint

I need to browse root directory in linux mint from command.

I tried

```
sudo cd /root
```

It says sudo cd command not found.

```
cd /root
```

says permission denied.

Also I need to list the files starting with "abc" inside root directory. When listing files I must not include sub directories of /root.

Can anyone help?

Comment: First off, you can't use `sudo` with `cd`. if you need a root propmt, either execute the shell as root, or run `sudo -i` to run a series of commands as root. second, the root dir is / , not /root. or better yet, use `sudo ls .... /root` to run your list command as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the root directory is `/`, not `/root`. `/root` is the home directory of the `root` user. Also, you don't need `sudo` to list its contents. Just do:

```
ls /
```

To list all files (and directories) starting with `abc`, you want

```
ls /abc*
```

To move into the root directory, just run `cd /`.

---

The command `ls /abc*` treats files and folders differently. The [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) is expanded by your shell (bash) to all files and folders beginning with `abc`. `ls` will list the *contents* of any directories you give it. For example:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jan 23 20:25 dfile.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jan 23 20:25 dir1
$ ls dir1
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Jan 23 20:25 file2.txt
```

So, I have a directory called `dir1` and a file called `dfile.txt`. The directory contains another file, `file1.txt`. Now, if I run `ls d*`, it will list the file `dfile.txt` and **the contents** of the directory `dir1`:

```
$ ls d*
dfile.txt

dir1:
file2.txt
```

If you don't want `ls` to list the contents of directories, run it with the `-d` option. As explained in `man ls`:

```
   -d, --directory
          list  directory entries instead of contents, and do not derefer‐
          ence symbolic links
```

So, for example:

```
$ ls -d d*
dfile.txt  dir1
```

To list all files and directories beginning with `abc` in `/` without listing dirctory contents, run this:

```
$ ls -d /abc*
```

Alternatively, if you want *only* files, use `find`:

```
$ find / -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "abc*"
```

From `man find`:

```
   -maxdepth levels
          Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of direc‐
          tories below the command line arguments. 
   -name pattern
          Base of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading  directories
          removed)  matches  shell  pattern  pattern.
   -type c
          File is of type c:

          d      directory
          f      regular file
```

Comment: @techfun see updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Root directory (the whole directory structure) is "/", not "/root".

If you do

```
sudo cd /
```

You will run a subshell that will change directory to `/` then exit. You are still where you were.

You can explore "/" simply by changing to it

```
cd /
```

and you'll be able to read the files that your user or group has the right to. Better than doing that as superuser... very dangerous.

I would hearthily advise you to have a look around here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-getting-started.htm